# Porperties of Presheafs, that extend globally.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

So i have the following statements:

[image]

I can prove 2 and 4 are true, but i struggle to decide whether 1 and 3 are true and false. I would say neither of them are true because thats the whole point to add the seaf property, right? But im not sure at all especially about 1.

Comment: $f_x$ = 0 means there is a nbd of $x$ on which $f=0$. Now under mild Noetherian conditions this would imply $f=0$ on $U$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why that is?

Comment: Because of Noetherianness you can cover $U$ by finitely many such $V_i$ on which $f=0$. Now by sheaf axiom $f=0$ on $U$

Comment: F is not a sheaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common counter-example to 1 and 3:
On $X=\{a,b\}$, we can declare a presheaf of rings (to be able to speak of units in the first place) by letting $\mathcal F(X)=\Bbb Z$, $\mathcal F(\{a\})=\mathcal F(\{b\})=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ (which also makes $\mathcal F_a=\mathcal F_b=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$), and the projections as restrictions. Then the global non-zero section $2$ is $0$ in each stalk, and the global non-unit section $3$ is a unit in each stalk.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what i was looking  for.